# Differnce between two dates includes both the dates

Tags: php

Difference between two dates includes both the dates
 For example

```
$date1=date_create("2015-01-01");
$date2=date_create("2015-01-03");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
```

**Output :**

```
+2 days
```

But I need to get `+3 days` as output like from starting date to ending date

Comment: use : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like as

```
$date1=date_create("2015-01-01");
$date2=date_create("2015-01-03")->modify("+1 day");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
```

**Output:**

```
+3 days
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/He4Y6)

Comment: You're Welcome. Glad it helped you. _(FYI: You can accept or upvote an answer which really helps you..)_

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
<?php
$date1 = date_create("2015-01-01");
$date2 = date_create("2015-01-03");
date_add($date2,date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 day'));
$diff = date_diff($date1, $date2);
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
?>
```